# Is any periodic $C^2$ function automatically analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

this might be a stupid question, but is any $C^2$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ of period $f(x+L)=f(x)$ automatically analytic (and in particular, infinitely often differentiable)?

I learned that for a $L$-periodic $C^k$ function with Fourier coefficients $f_n$, they converge to zero like $|f_n| |n|^k \to 0$ as $|n|\to \infty$.  So if $k\geq 2$, that would mean that the Fourier series converges absolutely and uniformly, right? So it would extend to an analytic funtion $f(z) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} f_n e^{i n z}$ and therefore, it is also $C^\infty$. Am I wrong here?

edit: ok, this is wrong. I thought the uniform convergence meant that $f(z) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} f_n e^{i n z}$ should be holomorphic, but of course that only works when we have uniform convergence on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, here it's only on an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\left| \sin \frac{x}{L} \right|^5$.

The first derivative is, by the chain rule $$f'(x)=5 \left| \sin \frac{x}{L} \right|^4 \left[ \text{sgn} \sin \frac{x}{L} \right] \left( \cos \frac{x}{L} \right) \frac{1}{L}$$ for $x \neq 0$. The derivative at $x=0$ can be computed from the definition $$f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left| \sin \frac{h}{L} \right|^5-0}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \left| \frac{\sin^5 \frac{h}{L}}{h} \right|=0. $$
This agrees with the formula for $x \neq 0$, since $\sin 0=0$. Differentiating a second time is more involved, but still possible.

Comment: Is it differentiable at $0$? Edit: oh, of course, ok.

Comment: @Brusko651 yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer. I also see the mistake in my thought process now.

Answer (score 2):

Even a $C^\infty$ periodic function need not be real analytic.  An example is
$$f(x) = \exp\left(\frac{-1}{\sin(x)^2}\right)$$
with $f(n \pi) = 0$.  Showing $f$ is smooth is a variation on a standard exercise.  But at $x=n\pi$, all derivatives of $f$ vanish, yet $f$ is not zero in any neighborhood of $x$.